# YACC Parser Doesn't want to print Accpeted even though the input is right?

Tags: yacc, lex

This program rules doesn't work on "zero one one" input why?

```
SS: S { printf("Accepted"); }
;
S: zero T one T one
;
T :  one T |
;
```

Comment: Doesn't that grammar generate a shift-reduce conflict warning?

Comment: Also, error output should *always* be sent to `stderr`, and lines should always be terminated with `\n`. If you don't do that, your error messages can get eaten. Other than that, it's hard to answer without knowing that your lexical scanner is working correctly. You should enable [parser debugging traces](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Tracing) to see where the parse error comes from.

Answer (score 0):

I tried running your grammar through Bison, and it produced two warnings:

> `warning: 3 shift/reduce conflicts [-Wconflicts-sr]`
> `warning: rule useless in parser due to conflicts [-Wother]`

The second warning applies to the production `T : %empty` which is the second alternative for `T`.

Although described as warnings, these messages almost always indicate a problem with your grammar, so they should be addressed (or at least mentioned if you're asking why your grammar doesn't work).

The shift-reduce conflict is to be expected. When the parser has seen a `zero`, it's in the state (• indicates the current parse position):

`S : zero • T one T one`

At this point, it has to decide whether the first or second production for `T` should apply. The second production involves immediately reducing `T` with an empty match. The first production involves shifting `one` as the first token in a new `T`.

The parser cannot tell which of these alternatives apply because in both cases the next token will be `one`. For shift actions, an LR parser doesn't need to make a decision; it can explore two different shift actions in parallel. But reductions need to be taken immediately or never; the terminal must be recognised when it ends. (For empty reductions, that's right away. But the fact that the reduction is empty doesn't stop it from having to be recognised.)

When Bison can't figure out what the parser should do in a given state, it reports a conflict and then uses a simple default strategy: prefer shift. Thus, the reduction of the empty `T` is removed from the grammar (which Bison also warned you about). Without that reduction, the parse can never terminate. Each `one` starts a new `T`, until the end of the input is reached. At that point, nothing more can be done (since the reduction was removed from the grammar) and the parser reports a syntax error.

Since I have no idea what sentences you expect to be able to recognise, I can't really offer you any good advice about how to fix the grammar.